# I can't ReplaceAll typescript

Tags: typescript

I tried replace "/" in my String date "2018/03/17" but I  get 2018-03/17

```
filterDateStart.replace (/ \ /g, '-');
```

I need 2018-03-17

Thanks.

Comment: Should it be `.replace(/\//g, '-')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect regex.

Correct one is this: `/\//g`

And you want it to use it this way `filterDateStart.replace(/\//g, '-');`

working example => https://plnkr.co/edit/5HutaCcRMpns2bo94TG4?p=preview

In regular expressions `/` is a reserved character and needs therefore to be escaped with a backslash `\`.

Comment: I added a life example. Are you sure you have `g` at the end and you are using the correct one?